# How to reroute an external DNS address to internal address, ONLY when on a local network?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ip, redirection

So I own my own personal server for files/media etc. I currently have my computer set up to do some syncing with my server, but there’s one problem.

When I’m on my home network, I have to use an internal IP to connect to my server, but when I’m away connected over the Internet, I use my domain name that I have set to redirect to my home network’s external IP.

I was wondering if there was a way to set it up so that Windows detects when I’m on my home network, and redirects my domain name to my internal IP, but *only* if I’m on my home network, then acts as normal when I’m not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [you have answered your own question](https://superuser.com/a/975306/167207) with a software solution, it seems what you are describing:

> I was wondering if there was a way to set it up so that Windows
>   detects when I’m on my home network, and redirects my domain name to
>   my internal IP, but *only* if I’m on my home network, then acts as
>   normal when I’m not.

Is actually a router/networking based concept known as [NAT loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) (aka: NAT hairpinning or NAT reflection). This works on any network connection; wired Ethernet or Wi-Fi. Here is an excerpt from the Wikipedia explanation of NAT loopback:

> NAT loopback, also known as NAT hairpinning or NAT reflection, is a
>   feature in many consumer routers which permits the access of a service
>   via the public IP address from inside the local network. This
>   eliminates the need for using separate domain name resolution for
>   hosts inside the network than for the public network for a website,
>   for example.
>
> The following describes an example network:
>
> - **Public address:** 203.0.113.1. This is the address of the WAN interface on the router.
> - **Internal address of router:** 192.168.1.1
> - **Address of the server:** 192.168.1.2
> - **Address of a local computer:** 192.168.1.100
>
> If a packet is sent to the public address by a computer at
>   `192.168.1.100`, the packet would normally be routed to the default
>   gateway (the router), unless an explicit route is set in the
>   computer’s routing tables. A router with the NAT loopback feature
>   detects that `203.0.113.1` is the address of its WAN interface, and
>   treats the packet as if coming from that interface. It determines the
>   destination for that packet, based on DNAT (port forwarding) rules for
>   the destination. If the data were sent to port 80 and a DNAT rule
>   exists for port 80 directed to `192.168.1.2`, then the host at that
>   address receives the packet.

So knowing that, I don’t believe NAT loopback is anything that can be implemented on an OS level without extra software; would like to be proven wrong. But—depending on the make and model of the router—it should be something that can be set up on the router.

I believe that alternative router firmwares like [DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com/), [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org) and [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) support NAT loopback so it might be worth looking into a nice router that supports any of those firmwares and see if that can be tweaked to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I actually found something that should work. This program called Switch Location is free and will switch your hosts file based on the ssid of the network that you are connected to. Now, this means that this program will only work when you are using Wi-Fi, but for my applications, that's all I need. The free program [can be found here](http://www.kevinblake.co.uk/switch-location/).